# Proper type for a one-to-one constant lookup table?

Tags: java

What is the proper Java type to use for a lookup table of constants that have a one-to-one relationship with other constants? For instance:

```
A1 <-> B1
A2 <-> B2
A3 <-> B3
```

where all As and Bs are known at compile time. I need to be able to call something like this in the code:

```
B = getB(A)
```

My initial thoughts were a Map or Enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the mapping to go one way (i.e. lookup B for A), then a `java.util.Map` implementation will do fine.

If you want the mapping to go both ways (i.e. lookup B for A and lookup A for B), then either use two `java.util.Map` instances or a bidirectional map interface; e.g. the Guava [BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface.

Comment: Hi Stephen, does that mean that for the key you provide, i.e. (Ax), you are guaranteed to get a unique value, (Bx) ?

Comment: Map and BiMap only support 1 to 1 relationships.  The difference is whether you can do lookups in one direction, or in both directions.  Isn't that what you mean by using double-headed arrows?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably best off hard coding a [Hashtable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) or [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
//HashMap example

HashMap<String, String> Constants = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    add("A1", "B1");
    add("A2", "B2");
    add("A3", "B3");
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

that's `java.util.Map` interface, you can have a look at its implementation classes.